# Read/Edit Textedit icloud files on an iPad

Tags: ios, icloud, textedit

Does any one of you know a solution to either read or edit on an iPad files stored with Textedit on iCloud ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, see [How to I access documents saved in iCloud with Mountain Lion on my iOS device](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57681/how-to-i-access-documents-saved-in-icloud-with-mountain-lion-on-my-ios-device)

Comment: Let's leave this open - the linked question is about more general Preview / PDF / Text and this one is razor sharp on text editing and iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @patrix said there is no way.

However you can use [iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/). It's an application available for Mac, iPad and iPhone, which allows you to read and write `txt` files, which are the same produced by Textedit. It as a native iCloud and Dropbox support.

Unfortunately it is not free.

Alternatively Brett Terpstra has [an amazingly comprehensive review of iOS editors](http://brettterpstra.com/ios-text-editors/) where you can find a replacement or be alerted when a program does in fact cooperate with TextEdit for document storage in iCloud.

Comment: Due to the way that iCloud works (each app has its own iCloud silo) there's no way an app can access other's app iCloud content without the collaboration of the original app's developer. So I guess there won't be any iOS apps supporting this anytime soon (unless Apple releases one and that's unlikely). iA Writer looks sweet, I may give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

using iCloud Drive w/ iOS 9 it is possible.

"On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iOS 9, you can access your files from the iCloud Drive app. To show or hide the app, go to Settings > iCloud > iCloud Drive. Next to Show on Home Screen, choose On or Off. On your PC with Windows 7 or later and iCloud for Windows, you can go to iCloud Drive in File Explorer"

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201104

necro, I know. I was searching and found this thread.