# How can I access TextEdit documents saved in iCloud on a PC?

Tags: icloud, windows, textedit, pc

I use TextEdit to store a number of notes for me, and now my Mac is in Apple repair, I can't access them.

- How can I use a PC to access these notes?
- Is it possible to use an iPad mini to access these notes?

**What I've done so far**

1. I logged into http://icloud.com and didn't see my documents under any available application.
2. I installed the iCloud app for PC and although I see the ability to sync "Mail, Contacts, Tasks with Outlook"  and sync "bookmarks" and "photo stream" ... none of them are "text files".

Comment: The answer to this question is basically the same as that seen here: [How to I access documents saved in iCloud with Mountain Lion on my iOS device](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57681/how-to-i-access-documents-saved-in-icloud-with-mountain-lion-on-my-ios-device)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

TextEdit files can only be accessed from TextEdit (That's how iCloud storage is made). Therefore you'll need a Mac connected to your iCloud account.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://developer.icloud.com and click on documents. You will find com~apple~TextEdit and you can download files but can't upload files.

Comment: Doesn't this require a (free) developer account?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with apple's developer account and works for every iCloud account.